# Regex for email, between 10 and 30 characters

Tags: regex, email, expression

I have to make regex expression for e-mail.
It is allowed to have letters or numbers only before the @ symbol, optionally only the dot that can not be on the start. After @ symbol it is allowed to have letters or numbers only, exactly one dot and after dot at least 2 characters.

That's my expression

```
/([a-zA-Z\d*])+(\.?)([a-zA-Z\d*])*@{1}([a-zA-z\d*])+(\.){1}([a-zA-Z\d*]){2,}/
```

Whole email should have between 10 and 30 characters, and I don't know how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: You should state the regex flavor and/or language in which you need the answer. Then however it will not be long before several duplicates of this question are found. Did you search for e.g. "regex email"? Did you look at the proposed similar questions you find under the  heading "Related" on the right of this page?

Comment: And don't forget: https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski  “Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.”

Comment: @JDługosz I am using this in college project, and I have to use it :(

Comment: A `*` inside a char range is just a `*`.  Always, `x` by itself means just one x. Writing `x{1}` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can prefix your pattern with a look-ahead and a quantifier to match between 10 and 30 characters: `(?=^.{10,30}$)`

Then, your pattern looks like this:

```
(?=^.{10,30}$)([a-zA-Z\d*])+(\.?)([a-zA-Z\d*])*@{1}([a-zA-z\d*])+(\.){1}([a-zA-Z\d*]){2,}
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/VJEOYb/1)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a range of allowed repeats is `{n,m}`.  You wrote `{1}` meaning "exactly one" which is pointless.  `{10,30}` is the range you are looking for.

Also, know the escape code for "letters". `\w` is a "word character", which is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. And why is there a '*' in the character range?

So the problem is that you have pieces which can end up being of various lengths, and need to check the *total* when done, right?

In Perl you can include code as a assertion.  So include `(?{ length($&) <= 30 })` as the final assertion.

Comment: {1} is for dot, I need to use exactly one dot,
\w -> I didn't know that \w is for digits too,
* is there because numbers are allowed, but not mandatory,

thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=^.{10,30}$)(?=^[A-Za-z0-9])[A-Za-z0-9\.]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/cBACF2/10

Should be between 10 to 30 `(?=^.{10,30}$)`
Start with letters & numbers `(?=^[A-Za-z0-9])`
contains letters & numbers and dot `[A-Za-z0-9\.]`
at least two letter after after last dot `[A-Za-z]{2,}`